# 3D rotation of coordinates axis

Tags: 3d, rotations, transformation

I am struggling to understand the 3D rotation. [image]

The initial object position is $A(x_1, y_1, z_1).$ We need rotate it into $A'(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ about $z$-axis by angle $\angle A'PA=\theta.$
And we take $P$ be the any point in $z$-axis. It makes $\angle APS=\phi.$

Now we find $cos \phi= \frac{PS}{OP}=\frac{x_1}{r}\Rightarrow x_1=rcos \phi.$ But we know $OQ =x_1$ but here slides take $PS =x_1$ and they forcefully match the answer which is wrong.

My question is slides has wrong or my concepts is wrong? If both are wrong so how we find 3D rotation about any coordinate axis?

Comment: Do you understand rotation in two dimensions ? If you do, then rotation in three dimensions about the $z$ axis is a straightforward extension of the 2-Dimensional rotation.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $P = (x, y, z) $ a point in $3D$.

We want to rotate $P$ about the $z$ axis.

Note that this rotation does not change the $z$ coordinate of $P$, and that the image of the $x$ and $y$ coordinates follow that of the usual $2D$ rotation.

Thus if $P' = (x', y', z')$ is the image of $P$ under a rotation about the $z$ axis by an angle $\theta$ then

$z' = z$

$x' = x \cos \theta - y \sin \theta $

$y' = x \sin \theta + y \cos \theta $

In matrix form

$\begin{bmatrix} x' \\ y' \\ z' \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta && - \sin \theta && 0 \\ \sin \theta && \cos \theta && 0 \\ 0 && 0 && 1 \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} x \\ y \\ z \end{bmatrix} $

Comment: No, it's not a answer that I am finding.. I am looking how to make angle and find cos... Please see my picture.. And tell what is the problem in my solution??

Comment: please zoom it.

Answer (score 1):

The following is a note on $3D$ rotation that I wrote a while ago.  Click on the image and ZOOM +.

[image: A note on 3D Rotation Matrix]

Comment: please help my this question. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4291739/3d-shearing-w-r-t-x-axis

Answer (score 0):

Following the notation in the question, we have the original point as $A = (x_1, y_1, z_1)$ and its image is $A' = (x_2, y_2, z_2) $

Define $r = \sqrt{x_1^2 + y_1^2} $

Then there is a unique angle $\phi \in [0, 2\pi) $

such that

$x_1 = r \cos \phi$

$y_1 = r \sin \phi$

$\phi$ is the angle that the vector extending from $(0, 0, z_1) $ to $(x_1, y_1, z_1)$ makes with the direction of the positive $x$ axis.

If we now rotate $A$ about the $z$ axis by an angle $\theta$ then we are effectively keeping the $z$ coordinate of $A$ constant, and change the angle $\phi$ to the angle $\phi + \theta$

Hence, the new coordinates of $A'(x_2, y_2, z_2)$ are:

$z_2 = z_1 $

$x_2 = r \cos(\phi + \theta)$

$y_2 = r \sin( \phi + \theta)$

Now we note that:

$\cos(\phi + \theta) = \cos \phi \cos \theta - \sin \phi \sin \theta $

$\sin (\phi + \theta) =\sin \phi \cos \theta + \cos \phi \sin \theta $

therefore,

$x_2 = (r \cos \phi) \cos \theta - (r \sin \phi) \sin \theta = x_1 \cos \theta - y_1 \sin \theta $

and

$y_2 = (r \cos \phi) \sin \theta + (r \sin \phi) \cos \theta = x_1 \sin \theta + y_1 \cos \theta$

Comment: OQ=x1 why you consider PS =x1??

Comment: Points $P$ and $A$ and $A'$ all lie in the same plane which is parallel to the $xy$ plane.  Point $P$ coordinates are $(0, 0, z_1)$.  The distance $PA = \sqrt{x_1^2 + y_1^2} = r $, and therefore the length $PS = r \cos \phi = x_1 $

Comment: OK...One thing tell if initial position of object is A(x1,y1,z1). Then how A is calculated? I mean from where to start to go x1 distance from O or P, then y1, z1?

Comment: Point $A(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ is given, it is the input to the rotation procedure, while the output (what we want to find out) is the coordinates of its image $A' (x_2, y_2, z_2)$

Comment: I want to know if Point A(x1,y1,z1) is given, then how to calculated x1, from origin,...then go vertical to find y1 then z1?

Comment: The point $A$ has three coordinates which are given to us in the problem, that means they are known to us and specified in the problem.  Thus we do not calculate them, because they are already known.  What we calculate are the three coordinates of the image $A'$ and these are $x_2$ , $y_2$, and $z_2$.

Comment: Why Points P and A and A′ all lie in the same plane?

Comment: By considering the figure that you supplied with the problem, point $P$ lies on the $z$ axis and it is **chosen** to have the same $z$ coordinate as that point $A$, hence making its coordinates $P = (0, 0, z_1) $.  And using common sense, the rotated point (the image) which is point $A'$ will also have the same $z$ coordinate which $z_1$.  To summarize:  $P = (0, 0, z_1), A = (x_1, y_1, z_1), and A' = (x_2, y_2, z_1) $.  Hence all three points lie on the plane $z = z_1$

Comment: One thing tell any point (x, y, z) exists in 3D, could I find it by first y, then z, then x or any arbitrary order?

Comment: ??? What does that mean ?

Comment: I mean if I have find any point (x, y, z) in 3D, then first go in x direction, y direction, then z direction. If I go first  y direction, then z direction and etc.... It's possible?

Comment: Please answer me..

Comment: Yes.  Definitely it is possible.   Any order you use will lead to the same point.

Comment: Now I am satisfied with your answer..

Comment: Great.  I am glad you are.

Comment: @In internet nowhere 3D rotation explain unavailable, they just tell formula like your first answer.

Answer (score 0):

This is a short note on $3D$ rotation that I wrote more than $6$ years ago.

[image]