# 3D shearing w. r. t. $x$-axis

Tags: geometry, 3d, coordinate-systems, rotations, transformation

Shearing in $X$ axis is achieved by using the following shearing equations-

$X_{new} = X_{old}, 
Y_{new} = Y_{old} + Sh_y × X_{old}, 
Z_{new} = Z_{old} + Sh_z × X_{old}.$

My question is during $Y_{new}$ and $Z_{new}$ calculations why $Sh_y,Sh_z$ is multiplying with $X_{old}$ respectively, why not any other constant? Every books, websites mention just formula not the reason.

Can anyone give pictorial representations how shearing is happening with explanation.

Comment: have a look here  https://pages.mtu.edu/~shene/COURSES/cs3621/NOTES/geometry/geo-tran.html

Comment: @black I want the reason mean intuition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's start in 2-D.

Then,  in the acception provided in [Wikipedia](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rz9aE.png),
A  *"shear keeping fixed the $x$ coordinate"* , or otherwise told
a *" shear along the $y$ axis"*  will be a deformation like the one depicted.

[image: Shear_1]

Each point will move parallel to the $y$ axis by a quantity
which is proportional to its distance from it, i.e.proportional
to the $x$ coordinate.

In fact , $A=(x,y)$ will move to $A'(x',y')$ in this way
$$
A = \left( {x,y} \right)\; \to \quad A' = \left( {x,y'} \right) = \left( {x,y + \Delta y} \right) = \left( {x,y + x\tan \theta } \right)
$$
that is
$$
\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 x' = x \\ 
 y' = y + kx \\ 
 \end{array} \right.
$$

Passing to 3-D, imagine the picture above reproduced on every section at constant $z$.
Clearly we will have
$$
\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 x' = x \\  y' = y + kx \\  z' = z \\ 
 \end{array} \right.
$$
i.e. a movement along $y$, proportional to $x$, at constant $x,z$.
It is also clear, by symmetry that  keeping the slide to be in the $y$ direction, thus at constant $x,z$,
the magnitude could be proportional to $z$ instead than $x$.
That means that  we are tilting the planes parallel to $x,z$ (normal to $y$) around the $z$ axis in the first case
and around the $x$ axis in the second.

[image: Shear_2]

Legend:

- take a  parallelepiped (grey-yellow)
- apply a shear in the $y$ direction, proportional to $x$ (grey -> lavender, yellow -> blue):
  the planes are tilted around their intersection with the plane $y,z$, parallel to $z$;
- if  the shear is still in the $y$ direction, but proportional to $z$, then you have the second picture,
  with a tilt around the intesections with the $x,y$ plane, parallel to the $x$ axis.

Finally we can compose the shear above with a shear along $z$, proportional to $x$, at constant$x,y$
to give
$$
\begin{array}{l}
 (I)\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 x' = x \\  y' = y + kx \\  z' = z \\ 
 \end{array} \right.\quad (II)\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 x'' = x' \\  y'' = y' \\  z'' = z' + mx \\ 
 \end{array} \right.\quad  \Rightarrow  \\ 
  \Rightarrow \quad (II) \circ (I) = (II) \circ (I) = \left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 x'' = x \\  y'' = y + kx \\  z'' = z + mx \\ 
 \end{array} \right. \\ 
 \end{array}
$$
which is the expression you are considering

Comment: @G what's the philosophy behind the shearing  w. r. t x-axis I mean intuition?

Comment: in physics (and engineering) the shear deformation is the sliding of plane slices of a body one over the other. Take a deck of cards on a table and slide horizontally the top card wrt. x,y, or intermediate direction. Suppose the friction is enough to drive also the cards below, but not so high to avoid some slipping ..

Comment: @G could you explain this statement--"That means that we are tilting the planes parallel to x,z (normal to y) around the z axis in the first case and around the x axis in the second."

Comment: @G what do you z-axis in first case? What do mean? Please explain little bit.

Comment: @Niyon: added picture to explain that

Comment: @G could you depicts what's the original picture and then I would understand shearing image...

Comment: @Niyon: added legend

Comment: @G one thing tell second point of Legend could be represents as, $$
\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 x' = x \\  y' = y + kx \\  z' = z \\ 
 \end{array} \right.
$$ and third point of Legend could be represents as, $$
\left\{ \begin{array}{l}
 x' = x \\  y' = y + kz \\  z' = z \\ 
 \end{array} \right.
$$       Am I correct?

Comment: yes, that's correct